# Is the adhesive between an LCD screen and surface glass toxic?

Tags: lcd

My old laptop has bubbles appearing between the screen itself and the glass. The screen itself works fine, but it's leaking a resin out of the screen edges. Is this resin dangerous in any way?

P.S. I know that cracked LCD screen fluid can be dangerous, but my LCD screen isn't cracked.

Comment: This question http://superuser.com/questions/324012/are-the-insides-of-lcd-monitors-dangerous may help.

Comment: @WayneJohnston I'm not sure if that's exactly the same fluid or not. Depends on if the fluid is indeed coming from the screen, or if it's some sort of adhesive used to bind the screen together (rather than the actual liquid from the LCD).