# can fluid from a broken laptop screen run into your computer and ruin it?

Tags: laptop, display, lcd, fluid

my laptop screen is broken.
and when i had it repaired they said there had been fluid in the machine, and that had to be repaired too. but i can't remember that i spilled some liquid on the machine, nor had there been any rain or so on the machine....
so i thought: can the fluid of the lcd screen have leaked into the machine ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are the insides of LCD monitors dangerous?](http://superuser.com/questions/324012/are-the-insides-of-lcd-monitors-dangerous)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the 100's of broken LCD screens I have seen, handled and repaired myself, no fluid was ever found outside of the panel itself. So it is very unlikely the fluid the repair shop found was related to the broken screen.

Did they say where the fluid evidence they found was? Was it in the lower body of the laptop? If so, it is even more unlikely since the screen is usually housed in separate plastics than the keyboard/motherboard, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Mine leaked out slowly over time...a few ml per week.  It was sticky and viscous.  It was found inside the laptop but not in large quantities.  It leaked onto the top of the laptop when the screen was closed.